# How does this virtual machine convert instructions to hexadecimal values?

Tags: c, vm-implementation

I'm learning about virtual machines and I came across this Wikipedia book thing, and it's really good. However, I'm at the section where the writer is explaining how he converts instructions such as:

```
loadi r0 #100
```

to

```
0x1064
```

And I have no idea how it works?
Can someone please explain this to me, here's the link in question http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Creating_a_Virtual_Machine/Register_VM_in_C

If you scroll down to **instruction codes** he talks about it, but it doesn't make sense to me, can someone explain to me like I'm 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The insctruction of `loadi r0 #100` becomes a 16-bit instruction.

The command `loadi` sets bits 11 to 15 (bits to the left) to 1:

```
0001xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

`r0` is for register 0, and sets bits 8 to 11.

```
00010000xxxxxxxx
```

The value 100 is placed in bits 0 to 7. Bits 4 to 7 are multiplied by 16, then added to value in bits 0 to 3. So 100 = 6 times 16 (equals 96) + 4.

```
0001_0000_0110_0100 (in binary, seperations for clarity)
1064 (in hexa)
```

Source: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Creating_a_Virtual_Machine/Register_VM_in_C#Instruction_codes

Comment: FYI, this would be 0xF064.

Comment: @RDub I noticed, was correcting when you made comment.

Comment: May I ask, how does he encode `add r2 r0 r1` since there are 3 'parameters' this time

Comment: @user3839220 Format for `add` seems to be `add target source1 source2`. Code for `add` is 2, the rest are numbers encoded on 4 bits. So: `add r2 r0 r1` in binary is `0010 0010 0000 0001`, or `2 2 0 1`

Comment: That makes sense, I was confused since it said for the immediate value it was bits 0-7, whereas there is no immediate value in this case. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: @user3839220 "Intermediate value" was for "loadi". Other commands have other information for bits 0 to 11.

Answer (score 1):

0x1064 represents a hexidecimal number (base 16).

```
This number represents multiple pieces of information:
bits 15-12 = 0001 (loadi)
bits 11- 8 = 0000 (register)
bits  7- 0 = 0110 0100 (value to load)

So in binary (base2) the instruction is 0001 0000 0110 0100.
Converting to hex (base 64) the instruction is 0x1064.
```

You can use a calculator program to help converting between decimal (base 10), binary, and hex.